# Is this an even or odd function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

The corrected exercise from my tutor states that the following is an odd function. I am pretty sure this is not true.

$$f: [-1,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{equation}
  =\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    x, & \text{if}\ x \in [-1,1) \\
    0, & \text{if}\ x \in [1,3)
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation} $$

Clearly for $ -1=x \in D$ we have $f(-x)=f(-(-1))=f(1)=0\neq -f(x)=-f(-1)=1$

Thus f is not odd.

Also $f(-x)=f(-(-1))=f(1)=0\neq f(x)=f(-1)=-1$

This f is not even.

Is this assumption correct? The professor stated that f is uneven.

Comment: Does "uneven" mean "odd" or simply "not even"?  I would have assumed the latter.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I trandlated it from German. In this case it means odd.

Comment: You're correct. I would also argue it can't be either because it is not defined on a symmetric interval, but that's personal taste.

Comment: Well, it is not odd, for the reason you give,

Comment: I note that the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) on even and odd functions specifically doesn't require a symmetric domain.  They just require that the functional equation hold for all $x$ such that $\pm x$ are in the domain.  Of course, that would imply that every function from the positive reals to the reals is both even and odd (since there are no such $x$) which seems like a poor definition to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reasons given in the question, the function is neither even nor odd.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be either even or odd, $x$ in the domain has to imply $-x$ in the domain.  So the domain has to be a symmetric neighborhood around $0$.  Here the domain is $[-1, 3)$ which does not have this symmetry.  Therefore, we have to render the function uneven.